# Merge [cli] and [command-line]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was surprised that [cli](/questions/tagged/cli) is not a synonym of [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line). More appropriately, both should be synonyms for [command-line-interface](/questions/tagged/command-line-interface).

Comment: What's your reasoning that the two are the same?

Comment: One is an abbreviation, right? Also, *command line* is short for *command line interface*.

Comment: Command line is the whole thing while a command line interface is how the user interacts with a command line application.

Answer (score 3):

Synonymized [command-line-interface](/questions/tagged/command-line-interface) to [cli](/questions/tagged/cli).

Comment: my first thought was that cli is *Common Language Infrastructure* an  ISO/IEC/ECMA-Standard (.NET). I think there are some question that need to be retagged.